# Cannot use newly installed MPICH mpich-3.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mpich

I intalled mpich-3.2.1 following the installation guide on [MPICH](https://www.mpich.org/documentation/guides/). There were no errors popping up during the installation. I added the `bin` subdirectory of my installation directory to my path and `source` it, However, the command `which mpicc` refers to the commands in openmpi which is the defaut mpi in Ubuntu 14.04.

Could somebody tell me how to make the newly installed `mpich3` work?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that the path referencing to the new mpich should be exported before `/usr/bin` where the openmpi-related commands locate in.